# Redirect non-www URLs to www on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redirect

I am new to GCP. I am setting up a static website with a storage bucket. I am wondering how/if it is possible to redirect non-www requests (i.e. example.com) to www (i.e. www.example.com) with a static website on GCP (given GCP does not honour .htaccess files).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same question with you running static website on top-level domain.

All you need to do is using DNS redirection.

http://redirect.center will solve your problem :)

Take the first solution on the page. 
Add A record with @ 54.84.55.102
Add CNAME with redirect -> example.com.redirect.center

Comment: That's a crazy workaround, but, it WORKED. 

Comment: If you want something new, try Netlify or Vercel to deploy your static website :)

Answer (score 1):

I just signed on for GCP and migrated my static website.
I have this same issue and have a report to their support. But with the long weekend, I don't expect a response before Tuesday May 30.

However, I was wondering if their "Hosting a Static Website" could eliminate this problem by "inverting" what they suggest:

1. Create the bucket name as the domain name i.e.
   bucketName=domainName=example.com (Their example has
   bucketName=www.example.com  domainName=example.com
2. Then create the CNAME record with www.example.com  CNAME (1h)
   c.storage.googleapis.com

I don't have a another domain to try this, nor can I disrupt the working www.example.com

BTW, I observed the following:

1. Cleared browser cache

   - In Chrome, with cache cleared, [http://]example.com gives "Site Not found"
   - Same with Microsoft Edge and Android (mobile phone) browser
2. Browser with cache

   - In Chrome [http://]www.example.com displays the home page
   - Then [http://]example.com displays the home page. (That is, if you have accessed the site using "www" previously, subsequent accesses
     without "www" work. But this is a function in the browser I believe,
     because the URL changes to www.example.com, and doesn't behave same with MS-Edge).
   - In Microsoft Edge [http://]www.example.com displays the home page.
   - But after this [http://]example.com still display "Site Not found"
   - Android browser functions same as Chrome in this regard. 
     I have not tried Safari.

Note:

1. "Site not found" is not the exact message, but the message
   essentially says that.
2. [http://] means it is optionally typed in

Comment: just wondering if they responded and a tried solution has been reached by anybody. thanks.

Answer (score -8):

You can use JavaScript to check the host name of the page. If the host name does not contain www, then you can redirect the user to the www domain. The following code should work:

```
if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("www.") < 0) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
}
```

Comment: if the user requests "example.com" it will not even load a page (gives ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) so I am unable to place any JS to do this.